# Couple of VB.Net lines in C#

Tags: .net

I am converting a project from VB.Net, and I have a few lines that I am unable to convert propperly.

`System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default(Me.Name)`

In this line, I understand that "Me.Name" has to be "this.Name", but the error is "Non-invocable member 'System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default' cannot be used like a method.".

I have correctly added System.Runtime.Caching to References

Also `return new string[];`. I have no idea how to convert this.

Thanks in advance,
René

Comment: You say you have no idea how to convert `return new string[];` - are you wanting to convert this *to* VB?

Answer (score 3):

It appears you want to call an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) (sometimes called the `Item` property). C# uses square-brackets `[]` for this purpose.

```
System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default[this.Name]
```

I would suggest two other changes:

1. If there's no ambiguity, you can leave out the `this.`
2. With the appropriate using directive (`using System.Runtime.Caching;`), the type doesn't have to be fully qualified.

---

```
 MemoryCache.Default[Name]
```